# Graph Laplacian on Vertexes and Edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-laplacian

The unnormalised weighted Laplacian of a weighted simple graph $G(V,E)$ is:

$$ L_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{split}
 -w_{ij} & \quad \text{if} \quad i \sim j \\
 w_{i} & \quad \text{if} \quad  i = j \\
 0 \quad & \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{split}
\end{cases} $$

Where $w_i$ is the sum of the weights neighbouring the vertex $i$. $L$ acts on a function $\phi(V)$ of the vertices.

$$L \phi (i) = \sum_{j/ i \sim j} w_{ij} (\phi_j - \phi_i)$$

This is interpreted as the discrete Laplace operator acting on the graph. But what if $w_{ij}$ depends on $\phi_i$ and $\phi_j$? In particular it is a function of their mean $w_{ij}(\psi_{ij}) = w_{ij} ((\phi_i + \phi_j)/2)$.

$$L \phi (i) = \sum_{j/ i \sim j} w_{ij} (\phi_i, \phi_j) (\phi_j - \phi_i)$$

The motivation for this was was for $\phi_i$ to not only depend on the differences between neighbouring vertexes $ (\phi_j - \phi_i)$ but also on the neighbouring edges $\psi_{ij}$. Is there any theory about these types of systems?